# Is biblatex popular?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

On our homepage, we're offering `bibtex` entries of our publications. The number of arXiv preprints among them is increasing, and `biblatex` supports arXiv better than `bibtex` does. Should we switch to `biblatex`, or are there many `bibtex` users who don't use `biblatex`? I'm asking about user numbers, not about which is "better".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What would be the problem with providing both?

Comment: Hmm… I smell opinion-based answers

Comment: Both user bases are popular.

Comment: @TeXnician the solution should be easy to set up, and easy for the user to understand. Before this issue I wasn't even aware of the extent to which `bibtex` and `biblatex` are different, so I wouldn't expect the user to.

Comment: @Johannes_B what's the proportion, how many `bibtex` users don't use `biblatex`?

Comment: Well it is easy to set up (differences can be computer-generated). And those who use `biblatex` know that they are using it so they are able to distinguish. The `bibtex` users could use that if they are unsure.

Comment: As phrased this question is tendentious. Could it be rephrased to "Offer bibtex or biblatex data?" which is the real question -- popularity is only part of it. Both are used *enough* that it would be good to accommodate both user-groups if you can. Rephrased, I think there are possibly useful things to say.

Comment: Where as BibTeX is around for 30 years, `biblatex` has been around for only ten years. Starting with a very small user base, the functionality grew and the user base grew. People using `biblatex` are individuals, which have taken that decision more or less aware of it. BibTeX on the other hand is used by individuals that don't know about the modern tool, or *journals* with a *never touch a running system* workflow. If one journal decides to use `biblatex` *from now on*, many users have to switch.

Comment: In our black and white world, we forget about other things like `jurabib` (kind of the first idea of a biblatex thing) and `amsrefs`. Some people use those as well.

Answer (score 5):

I think this question rests (largely) on a technical misconception. It's *true* that `biblatex` styles will (generally) elegantly support a range of data that `bibtex` ones won't. But there's no fundamental incompatibility because `biblatex` will handle gracefully more or less any valid `bibtex` data -- it just won't be able to do the additional things it wants to do. Meanwhile, `bibtex` doesn't care (much) if it is given additional information that `biblatex` can use but it can't. The worst that happens if you provide data or an entry type that `bibtex` can't use is that it will ignore it and warn. So you don't mostly have to *choose*.

The answer therefore, as with nearly all "data capture" problems is that you should capture and present the maximum amount of data unless it's very troublesome to do so. So, in the example you give, you provide the arXiv data: `biblatex` uses it, `bibtex` ignores it. Up to the user to choose if they care. In a few cases `biblatex` has different preferred fields (e.g. `date` vs `year`) and there you can either give both (best) or rely on `biblatex` to compatibly support the `bibtex` form where it can, as it does.

The really tricky area is with UTF8 support, because there there is a real difference. In that case it would be ideal to support both forms, but if you had to choose you'd better make `bibtex` as the basic one because generally speaking `biblatex` will handle the TeX-enabled ASCII form where `bibtex` simply won't handle UTF8 and the sort of user who is least likely to understand this is the one most likely to be bitten. Probably it would be best to try to store as UTF8 internally and convert to TeX-encoded form, but that's a detail.

So short answer: it's impossible to say which is more widely used (though in the fields that use either I'd guess it's probably `bibtex`). But that's not exactly the right question, because things change, and anyway it should be possible to support both formats without much difficulty and without (generally) requiring users to choose or know which they need.